# Cannot Access Getter Method on __proto__

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was learing prototypes in Javascript and got a lot about their usages. But I'm confused about the following that how it didn't work.

```
function Employee(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

Employee.prototype.code = "SIMPLE";
Employee.prototype.getName = function()
{
    return this.name;
}

var a = new Employee("Manish");
var b = new Employee("Vikash");

a.__proto__.code // SIMPLE
a.__proto__.getName() // Undefined
```

Why we can't access a function on `__proto__` while `a.__proto__ == Employee.prototype` returns true.

Comment: `__proto__` is not a feature. Don't use it ...

Comment: I know it is discouraged. But why it is behaving like this?

Comment: You are not returning `this` from `Employee` so a should be undefined

Comment: @joel nope, thats a constructor.

Comment: Oops, I completely ignored the `new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* access the function on the `__proto__` object like you expect - but you're getting this behavior because you lose the binding to `this` when you call it this way so the function is not returning what you expect. The value of `this` is determed by the calling context. For the purpose of experimenting, you can try adding the binding back like this:

```
a.__proto__.getName.bind(a)()
// Manish
// or
a.__proto__.getName.call(b)
// Vikash
```

Answer (score 2):

The *context* ( aka this ) is determined in javascript when you call a function. So here:

```
a.__proto__.getName()
```

the context is *a.__proto __* , and that has not a *name* property, so it returns undefined. Here:

```
a.getName()
```

you call getName with the context being *a*, and a has a name...

Comment: In other words **`this`** will be whatever before the **`.`**.